# How to get string between double quotes only when first quote has a specific word before it using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing

Hi all i got a sample string that want to parse all values infront of data-videoid(for example values 123456 and 123457). My current code does not output the expected data(123456 and 123457) could you guys help me fix it.Thanks

```
<script>
    function getVideoIds2()
    {

    var MyData ="<div class=\ "col-ab-1 col-dn-2 video-see-cont\">\n\n <i class=\ "watch\" data-videoid=\ "123456\" data-la-action=\ "click\" data-la-label=\ "toco-video-eye\" data-la-value=\ "123456\" tabindex=\ "0\"></i>\n </div>\n\n </div>\n </li>\n ....<div class=\ "col-ab-1 col-dn-2 video-see-cont\">\n\n <i class=\ "watch\" data-videoid=\ "123457\" data-la-action=\ "click\" data-la-label=\ "toco-video-eye\" data-la-value=\ "123457\" tabindex=\ "0\"></i>\n </div>\n\n </div>\n </li>\n ";
    var regex = /\data-videoid(.*?)\data-la-action/g;
    var myArray;

    while ((myArray = regex.exec(MyData)) != null)  
    {  
      alert(myArray[1])
    } 

    };
    </script>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. ("Doctor, I'm sick. What should I do?") Please specify precisely. (1) the behaviour you observe, (2) the behaviour you expect, (3) how they differ.

Comment: I mean i get no output!

Comment: Why do you write `/\data…` instead of just `/data…`? `\d` is very different from `d`

Comment: Also, the title of your question has no obvious relationship to your question. And many of the backslashes in your example code seem to be followed by extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `\data-videoid(.*?)\data-la-action` is matching something different than you expect.

- `\d` matches a digit
- Than you would match `ata-videoid`
- Capture zero or more characters non greedy in a group `(.*?)`
- `\d` matches a digit
- Match `data-la-action`

That would match for example:

> 1ata-videoid="1ata-la-action
>
> 1ata-videoid1ata-la-action

The `var MyData =` in your example Javascript contains a space before escaping a double quote but does not contain a space afterwards.  For example in `class=\ "col-ab-1 col-dn-2 video-see-cont\"`

If it is the case that this white space should not be there so that it will be an escape like at the end, then this could be an approach:

```js
function getVideoIds2()
{
    var MyData ="<div class=\"col-ab-1 col-dn-2 video-see-cont\">\n\n <i class=\"watch\" data-videoid=\"123456\" data-la-action=\"click\" data-la-label=\"toco-video-eye\" data-la-value=\"123456\" tabindex=\"0\"></i>\n </div>\n\n </div>\n </li>\n ....<div class=\"col-ab-1 col-dn-2 video-see-cont\">\n\n <i class=\"watch\" data-videoid=\"123457\" data-la-action=\"click\" data-la-label=\"toco-video-eye\" data-la-value=\"123457\" tabindex=\"0\"></i>\n </div>\n\n </div>\n </li>\n ";
    var regex = /data-videoid="(\d+)/g;
    var myArray;

    while (myArray = regex.exec(MyData)) {
        console.log(myArray[1]);
    }
}
getVideoIds2();
```

The regex [`data-videoid="(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/f5Yws5/1)

- Will search for `data-videoid="`
- Then capture one or more digits in a group `(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
/data-videoid=[\\ ]*?"(\d+)/g
```